# How to assign multiple names simultaneously to a C# class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, syntax

Is there a way in which a C# class can be given multiple names, eg:

class Foo{}

class AlternativeFooName refers to Foo

I want to be able to access Foo through both names, Foo and AlternativeFooName but without having to inherit from Foo.

An application for this would be giving a class a long descriptive name but being able to abbreviate it when it is used, eg:

instead of
Foo f= new Foo();
being able to use the following with the same effect:
F f= new F();

Comment: Does `using AlternativeFooName = Foo;` work for you?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that the overhead (in terms of developer comprehension of code) of having to deal with the same class having many names could be offset by the small advantage of typing less characters to use such a class.  Also, with Intellisense, it almost seems completely needless, because one can often access a class without having to type the entire name.

Comment: @Kibbee: as is usually the case, "it depends". I find type-aliases nice when I have two ambiguously named classes which belong to different assemblies, which happens more often than you think (e.g. when gluing together two different vendors systems, and everyone has their own Customer or Order class). Why disambiguate Initech's Customer class from MegaCorp's Customer with a fully qualified namespace when a type-alias is much easier on the wrists.

Comment: The name should be a succinct yet sufficiently descriptive name, and you should put a 'long description' in the documentation / comments for the class.

Comment: @Juliet: If the reasoning was to resolve clashing namespaces, I would say that's a good reason to do it. Although I'd probably opt for extending the length of the class.  ie, Customer = AbcCustomer where Abc is a shorthand for the namespace it resides in.  As the only reason for needing multiple names was listed as "to reduce typing" it seemed like a somewhat bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.  I also agree that class names should be as descriptive as possible, but in certain situations, the meaning of nondescriptive names is well known in the local context, and one strives for code brevity and clarity.  For these reasons, I did not want to simply replace my descriptive class name with a shorter one.  Instead, I wanted to get the best of both worlds by having an "alias," as Juliet said, that would allow my code to be concise yet keep the rest of the code self-documented.

Comment: Thanks to Gabe too, for a correct solution to my problem in his comment!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the using directive applies to classes as well, for example:

```
using C = System.Console;
```

Comment: Thank! Precisely what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `using` statement, e.g.:

```
using Foo = My.Namespace.LongFoo;
```

Comment: Note that this is a using *directive*. The using *statement* is "using(Stream s = new FileStream blah blah blah..."

Comment: Thank! Precisely what I needed!

Comment: Sorry I could not mark your answer correct (because only one is allowed, although I voted also for yours.).  But thank you very much for answering!