# Multiple names for the same class?

Tags: perl

Please refer this question

[How to assign multiple names simultaneously to a C# class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787339/how-to-assign-multiple-names-simultaneously-to-a-c-sharp-class)

How can we achieve the same in Perl?

Comment: Why would you want to do so?  What would be the advantage of doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not "allowing multiple names".

It's "aliasing" an existing name.  In the case you cited, the C# "using" directive allows you to refer to a namespace or class by a different name:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

And there are several alternatives to create an "alias" in Perl, including using the "[aliased](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/aliased)" module:

- http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/aliased

Comment: TIMTOWTDI: [`as`](http://p3rl.org/as)